# Would it be possible to use a solid state relay as a dimmer switch?

Tags: solid-state-relay

I wanted to make a smart switch with a dimmer using an arduino and a solid state relay. I was wondering if this would be possible and if their would be any problems if I tried to do so. Also, the switch would be controlling 6 light bulbs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a random, not zero-crossing, switching SSR and you will need to get the zero crossings into your Arduino through something like an optoisolator, so you can time the delays to triggering on each half-cycle.

The latter would look something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhd3hH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Everything to the left of the optoisolator on the above schematic and the output terminals of the SSR are at mains potential, and proper precautions must be taken for safety. Best to have someone local have a look at it to make sure it's safe before applying mains power- you could hurt yourself or permanently damage your computer or other property.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You need to look for a SSR without zero crossing switching; ie one you can trigger at any point during the AC cycle.

Comment: thanks! is it more common for a ssr to have zero crossing or not?

Comment: I think they are equally common, but have not looked recently. Spehro makes a good point about a zero cross detector, but I would use one that has two LEDs back to back in it; I have seen low current SSRs that have both these elements in them